# How do I change settings for "fetchmail authentication failed on ___" notices?

Tags: email

Fetchmail polls an ISP server that is always congested (we don't own that server and can't fix it). 1 out of every 20 attempts, roughly, results in an `authentication failure` response from that server. It's not actually an authentication problem since it works the other 19 out of 20 items, its actually a busy response.

In any case, the net result is that we get 20-30 messages every day that say:

```
fetchmail authentication failed on ___
```

followed immediately by:

```
fetchmail authentication OK on ______
```

Is there any way to make fetchmail try several times before sending this message? Or to disable it completely for certain servers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be possible to suppress the message by not running in daemon mode.

From https://lists.berlios.de/pipermail/fetchmail-users/2012-January/003031.html:

> The workaround would be to use a shell script to emulate the ""
>   mode, and not use it (because the e-mail warnings only get sent in
>   daemon mode). You may have to use grep -v to kill the message there,
>   too, if you don't want it in the logs (not shown in the example below)
>   and redirect the remainder of the output into the log file, such as:

```
while true ; do
  fetchmail >>/home/users/srolinso/fetchmail/log/fetchmail_etg.log \
    -d0 \
    -f /home/users/srolinso/fetchmail/fetchmail_etg
  sleep 10
done
```